# Stuck white pixel in iOS app

Tags: ios

I've got this weird issue with my iOS app where a stuck pixel often appears after a while using the application and I can't find where it came from.

[image: Stuck pixel]

I've even done the following with LLDB and it is still there:

```
expr [((UIWindow *)((UIApplication *)[UIApplication sharedApplication]).keyWindow) setHidden:YES] // and removeFromSuperview
```

The pixel disappears when you close the app and reappears when you open it again.

Any ideas on how I can debug this further? Unfortunately I haven't managed to reproduce it consistently.

EDIT: this managed to remove the pixel:

```
[(UIWindow *)[(NSArray *)((UIApplication *)[UIApplication sharedApplication]).windows objectAtIndex:2] setHidden:YES]
```

The objectAtIndex 2 was:

```
<UITextEffectsWindow: 0x14de6280; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x14dd77a0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x14deb7f0>>
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: narrowed it down more. The pixel was removed while debugging by doing this:

```
expr [((UITextMagnifierCaret *)[(NSArray *)((UIWindow *)[(NSArray *)((UIApplication *)[UIApplication sharedApplication]).windows objectAtIndex:2]).subviews objectAtIndex:0]) remove]
```

Comment: Last time I had a surprising bug like this, I made a copy of my project and deleted pieces (from the code and nibs) until the problem was resolved. It wasn't very elegant, but you'll likely eventually delete something and the white pixel will be gone on the next build. Good luck!

Comment: Do you know which view this is? Is it a view with a custom `drawRect:` or subviews?

Comment: It turned out it was something to do with a UITextEffectsWindow (updated question)... any ideas?

Comment: @BergQuester no custom drawing is going on here (I'm using SpriteKit)

Comment: Does the UITextEffectsWindow have children?

Comment: Yeah, a UITextMagnifierCaret